# Узнать пароль рута по файлам

Tags: linux, readonly

Привет всем, теоретически имея доступ ко всем файлам на сервер(только чтение), я могу узнать пароль от любого пользователя ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пароли в *nix системах лежат обычно в /etc/shadow (раньше лежали в /etc/passwd). только там хеши от паролей, их невозможно просто расшифровать. единственный способ получения пароля это шифровать все возможные строки и сверять полученный хеш. так что если пароль легкий, вы его конечно быстро подберете, но если длиннее 8-ми символов на подбор могут уйти годы (тысячелетия)

Comment: а ГПУ не имеет параллельные вычисление ?

Comment: @Cus Имеет, пару биткоин-ферм перенастройте на подбор, может и поберете если он не очень длинный.

Comment: А не преувеличение ли это ?

Comment: @Cus У меня в системе например используется SHA-512. При том, что в основе биткоина лежит SHA-256, гораздо более слабая версия. если вы придумаете как однозначно подобрать SHA-256 то все биткоины мира будут вашими. С другой стороны конечно шифрование пароля происходит гораздо быстрее, потому что шифруется короткий блок. так что сложно сказать преувеличение это или нет.

Comment: а sha256 забрутить возможно ?

Comment: @Cus попробуйте. готовых программ куча. заодно и скорость посмотрите. Может там пароль вообще 123 :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70750/discussion-between-cus-and-mike).

Comment: Мне кажется, что вопросы подобные этому, не стоит обсуждать на форуме программистов. Ну есть же всякие  хакерские форумы - вот там и спрашивайте!